# Take values with sed or awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

In a log file, I've a line on the form

```
2014-10-09 13:03:01.095@LM_TRACE@ [Functions::setRotate(float, float, float)]  3D,  H:359.08847, P:0.24604176, R:0
```

How can I use `sed` (or `awk` or whathever) in order to retrieve three float values `H, P, R`? I need to store them in a .csv file.

Comment: What would be expected output?

Comment: The row should be `359.08847, 0.24604176, 0`

Comment: is the values are in order?

Comment: Yes, it's the same order of H, P, R that are at the end of the row.

Comment: You could do this with only native bash only, btw, no sed _or_ awk strictly required (though using awk will be faster when you're processing the whole file rather than already having the line in-memory). Assuming an answer in your question ("how do I do X with Y or Z", vs "how do I do X") means you miss out on some potentially interesting answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give this "quick & dirty"  a try:

```
awk -F' H:| P:| R:' '{$1=""}7' file
```

outputs:

```
 359.08847, 0.24604176, 0
```

Comment: Nice. This also does not track log lines that don't match the pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this simply through grep,

```
$ grep -oP '(H|P|R):(\d+(\.\d+)?)' file
H:359.08847
P:0.24604176
R:0
```

OR

```
$ sed 's/.*H:\([0-9.]*\), *P:\([0-9.]*\), *R:\([0-9.]*\)$/\1, \2, \3/' file
359.08847, 0.24604176, 0
```

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to have them in the form `359.08847, 0.24604176, 0`?

Answer (score 2):

With sed, it would be something like this:

```
sed 's|.*H:\(.*\), P:\(.*\), R:\(.*\)|\1, \2, \3|' infile.txt > outfile.csv
```

Use `-n` to not display the lines that do not match, and `p` to print the ones that do.  For example:

```
sed -n 's|.*H:\(.*\), P:\(.*\), R:\(.*\)|\1, \2, \3|p' infile.txt > outfile.csv
```

Comment: This is useful, but it leaves untouched log lines that does not match the pattern. This is a nice command anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @Jepessen Edited based on your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F '[HPR]:' -v OFS=', ' '{gsub(/ *, */, ""); print $2, $3, $4}' file
359.08847, 0.24604176, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `KSH` script like

```
the_script < logfile 

 #!/bin/ksh
 read line 
 line=${line#*\(} 
 line=${line%\)*} 
 line=${line//,/} 
 print ${line} | read R1 R2 R3 
 print "result: $R1;$R2;$R3"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
while read line
  do
    echo "$line" | sed 's/.* H:\(.*\) P:\(.*\) R:\(.*\)/\1 \2 \3/' 
    | awk '{print $1 $2 $3}' >> file.csv
done < log.txt
```

This one works, as well